# Save Eclipse E4 application model programatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

While there is an option to load the E4 application model programmatically, is there any way to save the E4 application model programmatically?

Would like to make some changes to the model and save it during application shutdown (`UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_SHUTDOWN_STARTED`)?

Comment: The application model is persisted to the workbench.xmi file automatically during shutdown.

Comment: I want to make some changes to the application model before the shutdown. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@PreSave` annotation in your [LifeCycle](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) class to run code just before the model is saved.

```java
@PreSave
public void preSave(EModelService modelService)
{
  // TODO modify the model using the model service
}
```

You can force the model to be saved to the 'workbench.xmi' file using

```java
@Inject
IModelResourceHandler handler;

...

handler.save();
```

It is also possible to write you own IModelResourceHandler [see here](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/07/22/replacing-the-eclipse-4-persistence-for-the-application-model/)

Comment: @Presave method is called just before application model is saved. But my question is how to save the application model itself programmatically?

Comment: Added IModelResourceHandler details

Comment: Thanks, that saves the model.